# js массивы запись в переменную

Tags: javascript

На странице есть

```
div class="slider__two" и div class = "slider__two slider__noactive"
```

получить их через `document.querySelectorAll('.slider__two');` и перебрать через цикл и записать `div class = "slider__two"` в переменную `а`,

`div class = "slider__two slider__noactive"` в переменную `b`. Возможно ли это осуществить таким способом? и как, или есть другие способы.

Знаю что можно это сделать путем просто добавить разные классы к дивам и через document.querySelector по отдельности их получить, но стало интересно возможно ли такое решение.

Comment: А в чём смысл такого, я извиняюсь, "танца с бубном"? В чём преимущество?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понял, вы хотите получить `.slider__two` с классом `.slider__noactive`
и также `.slider__two` без класса `.slider__noactive`
Я бы для этого использовал просто CSS селекторы

`.slider__two:not(.slider__noactive)` без класса
`.slider__two.slider__noactive` с классом

```js
const a = document.querySelectorAll('.slider__two:not(.slider__noactive)');
const b = document.querySelectorAll('.slider__two.slider__noactive');

a.forEach(item => {
  item.innerHTML += ' без класса slider__noactive';
});

b.forEach(item => {
  item.innerHTML += ' c классом slider__noactive';
});
```

```html
<div class="slider__two">1</div>
<div class="slider__two">1</div>
<div class="slider__two">1</div>
<div class="slider__two slider__noactive">2</div>
<div class="slider__two slider__noactive">2</div>
<div class="slider__two slider__noactive">2</div>
```

Comment: спасибо не знал  про ```const a = document.querySelectorAll('.slider__two:not(.slider__noactive)');
const b = document.querySelectorAll('.slider__two.slider__noactive'); ```